# R - extract column names using shell or another method for faster import

Tags: r, bash, shell, csv

I am working with a big csv file and I am looking for ways to make importing it faster in read.table for the colClasses switch.

Currently I have this function:

```
getColumnNames <- function (file) {
 system(paste("head -1 ", file), TRUE)
}
```

this gets the first line of the CSV but in this way:

```
[1] "\"\",\"p_id\",\"Name\",\"Country\",\"person_degree\",\"person_email_value\"
```

Is there any way using strsplit or another method to make this in to a vector that can be used for ColClasses to faster the read.table process?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `fread` function from package data.table.

Comment: You could just use `read.csv` with `nrows=1` and `header=T`. That should be pretty quick and you can just take the names from that.